# Matriz identidad

Tags: c#

Debo hacer una matriz identidad y no sé como iniciar el algoritmo.

Comment: Hola. Tienes 5 preguntas sin cerrar (no has aceptado respuestas). También sabes que no resolvemos ejercicios completos, salvo que demuestres algún tipo de esfuerzo. Mejora tu consulta (mira [ask]). En su formato actual, tu pregunta es muy amplia

Comment: como las cierro? como acepto la respuesta para poder cerrarla

Comment: @jorge solo tienes que darles por aceptadas, visita nuevamente el recorrido: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y se te explicará. Al revisar tu pregunta tal cual la planteas es demasiado amplia, revisa [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se define como la matriz diagonal que tiene valor 1 en cada una de las entradas de la diagonal principal, y 0 en el resto. Así, en una matriz identidad de 5x5 seria:

```
1    0    0    0    0
0    1    0    0    0
0    0    1    0    0
0    0    0    1    0
0    0    0    0    1
```

Ya sabiendo que es una mariz identidad, deberia ser facil implementar el codigo en C#.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias , voy a iniciar con esa explicación